# Exact or Approximate match in String Comparison - JAVA

Tags: java, string

I have a Vast list of Strings in an ArrayList. I need to compare my input string with the entire list and return the Exact Match or the approximate match. How can I achieve this in Java ?

Comment: define "approximate match". Also, is "appropriate match" in your question a typo for "approximate match"?

Comment: Exact Match or the "appropriate match" ??

Comment: That is Approximate match.. Apologies for the typo error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute the hamming edit distance between your search string and each string in your list. Pick the string or strings with the lowest edit distance. If you have to support strings that might need to add or remove characters to match the search string, use the Levenshtein distance..

Comment: Antiduh, I have used Levenshtein distance. But i am wondering how i should filter the string if more than 1 entry is returned with the lowest edit distance.For eg: Original string is Pink. The values Sink,Link and Ink returns 1. Can you pls throw some light on this ?

Comment: That depends on you - to what end are you trying to find best match?

Answer (score 0):

try=

> ArrayList.contains("StringToBeChecked");
>   If the String is present in the ArrayList, this function will return true, else will return false.

Comment: No doubt this works well for "exact" Strings.. but if he wants "approximate/nearest match" String(s), then antiduh's answer is more appropriate.. :)